Launch iOS app when a bluetooth device connects
I saw that apps like myBMW opens in foreground from a terminated state when the car automatically connects to the iPhone.
I want to open an iOS app when connected to hardware. Is that achievable with Swift programming or does it have to be done especially on the Bluetooth hardware?

To launch an iOS app when connecting to hardware you need to be a member of the MFi Program.
So, if you’re going to manufacture your own hardware for end users you can apply for MFi.
Per the MFi program guidelines you do not need to join MFi and likely would not be granted the required MFi entitlements for personal projects.
Also, you implied that you’d like to build an app that opened when connected to a third-party product — a car. You should check to see if that would violate the MFi license agreement.

So you're claiming a car contains an iBeacon?

I’m sorry. I inferred you wanted to open apps without connecting to hardware. I’ll write a better answer now.

I am not the OP. But I can read the question. This doesn't seem to me to respond to it.
